# asp dropdown reload page when setting dropdown.selectedvalue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following asp dropdown:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ArticleCategories" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" CssClass="ArticleCategoriesDropDown" onselectedindexchanged="mCategoryItemSelected" AutoPostBack="True"> 
        <asp:ListItem Text="Select Category" Value="" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Once a selection has been made, and the data loaded, I want to set the value in the dropdown to display the value chosen by the user.

I am doing this by:

```
ArticleCategories.SelectedValue = CategoryID.ToString();
```

This works fine the first time, but from then the page is stuck on that selection, as the selected value gets loaded before the new value can load.

I have tried disabling the itemchangelistener by:

```
ArticleCategories.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(doNothing);
```

But that does not work.

I have also tried to disable postback which also does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only set the selection when loading the page the first time. In ASP.NET, you can achieve this by checking the [`IsPostBack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    ArticleCategories.SelectedValue = CategoryID.ToString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do Autopostback= false

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ArticleCategories" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" CssClass="ArticleCategoriesDropDown" onselectedindexchanged="mCategoryItemSelected" AutoPostBack="False"> 
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select Category" Value="" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey before selecting another item from `Dropdown` you should clear previous selection then selected another one.

```
ArticleCategories.ClearSelection();
```

Hope it helps you.